# Matplotlib add labels to individual stacks in a stacked chart for imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, stacked-chart

I am trying to plot a graph based on a huge imbalanced dataset using matplotlib and it looks something like

[image]

I want to represent % values on each bar, but they all seem cluttered/messy when the stacks get really small. The dataset is dynamic, and I cannot modify it.

I tried playing around with [matplotlib.text](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/text_api.html), but couldn't figure out a way to get past this.

```
def plot_stack_bar(plot_df, xlabel, ylabel, title):
    
    plot_df_percent=pd.DataFrame()
    cols = list(plot_df)
    plot_df_percent[cols] = plot_df[cols].div( plot_df[cols].sum(axis=1), axis=0 )
    
    plot_df.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(20, 17))
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.title(title)


    for n, x in enumerate([*plot_df.index.values]):
        i=0
        for (proportion, y_loc) in zip(plot_df_percent.loc[x],
                                       plot_df_percent.loc[x].cumsum()):
           
            y_loc = plot_df.iloc[n,I] / 2 + plot_df.iloc[n,:i].sum()
            plt.text(x=n-0.17,
                     y=y_loc,
                     s=f'{np.round(proportion * 100, 1)}%', 
                     color="black",
                     fontsize=12,
                     fontweight="bold")
            i=i+1
    plt.savefig(f'draft/{title}.png')        
    plt.show()
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Maybe you could represent the data with a log-scale non-stacked lineplot. Or, if the small values aren't that important, only label the bars which have some minimal height?

Comment: Can't skip the small values @JohanC.

Comment: If you don't like the log-scale non-stacked lineplot, the only viable alternative I see, is to add a separate table with all the values. At least, if you need a static plot.  If you want something interactive, however, the sky is the limit.